# Test whether a Ruby class is a subclass of another class

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I would like to test whether a class inherits from another class, but there doesn't seem to exist a method for that.

```
class A
end

class B < A
end

B.is_a? A 
=> false

B.superclass == A
=> true
```

(N.B. the `is_a?` test above does not make any sense, as the first comment correctly points out `B.new.is_a?(A)` would make sense, but is not generally applicable, as not every class has a #initialize method that accepts 0 arguments)

A trivial implementation of what I want would be:

```
class Class
  def is_subclass_of?(clazz)
    return true if superclass == clazz
    return false if self == Object
    superclass.is_subclass_of?(clazz)
  end
end
```

but I would expect this to exist already.

Comment: `A.class #=> Class`. This is why `B.is_a? A` returns false.

Comment: what about `kind_of?`

Comment: `kind_of?` tests whether an object is an _instance_ of a class. Not whether the object inherits from a class.

Comment: `kind_of?` is an alias of `is_a?`

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Just use the [`<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-3C) operator

```
B < A # => true
A < A # => false
```

or use the `<=` operator

```
B <= A # => true
A <= A # => true
```

Comment: This works...curious if anyone knows why `is_a?` doesn't though?  Thanks!

Comment: @Brian Because `is_a?` translates to *is instance of*. `B` isn't an instance of `A`, `B.new` is though (`B.new.is_a? A # => true`).

Comment: Hmm, strange syntax (wouldn't have been my first guess), but thanks for the clarification!

Comment: For documentation see [Core API / Module / #<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3C).

Comment: My love/hate relationship with Ruby continues… Why provide a different function for an operator used for declaring class relationships AND provide two different ways of doing it?

Comment: @BenGotow - 1. Because < is not an operator, it's a method. 2. Because < only checks for a subclass, and <= also includes self.

Comment: Haha, I don't know it so simple like that, I thought it'd be more complicated. Thank you so much!

Comment: this is the correct answer, use `thing.class < X` instead of `thing.is_a? X`, because the second version includes modules

Comment: `module#<` *does* include modules as well

Answer (score 69):

Also available:

```
B.ancestors.include? A
```

This differs slightly from the (shorter) answer of `B < A` because `B` is included in `B.ancestors`:

```
B.ancestors
#=> [B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

B < B
#=> false

B.ancestors.include? B
#=> true
```

Whether or not this is desirable depends on your use case.

Comment: More readable: `B <= B` (same result as `B.ancestors.include? B`).

Comment: Update: The immediately preceding solution works with 1.9+ whereas there is no "ancestors?" in 1.9.

Comment: @Barry I do not see `ancestors?` mentioned in any answer on this page, including this one. To what are you referring?

Comment: Update^2: The immediately preceding solution works with 1.9+ whereas I don't see "ancestors" in 1.9.  ---   Ambiguity corrected.  My bad, I thought I was asking a question while using the overformal "Are these double-quotes sexy?" syntax.

Comment: This will not confuse people not familiar with the '<' syntax, and for that reason I prefer it.

Comment: I note that this answer iterates through all ancestors, which might take a while. Is `B < A` meaningfully faster, or do they do the same thing behind the scenes?

Comment: @SimonLepkin Probably not "a while", unless you can experience microseconds ticking by. ;) Yes, behind the scenes the `include?` and `<` methods [loop through the ancestor chain](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/class.c#L1023). It does this in C, so surely faster than looping through the Ruby array...but practically the two should be indistinguishable.

Comment: @Phrogz Could you please explain me why `B.ancestors` returns itself `B` also? Should not it be `[A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` ?

Comment: @JunanChakma Based on how the English word "ancestors" is defined, I agree that the return value should not include `B`. But it does. The [method documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) says, _"Returns a list of modules included/prepended in mod (**including mod itself**)."_ (emphasis mine). I'm guessing it includes its own class for convenience when using `.include?`, but that's just speculation on my part.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks!